# How to make datapoints underlay the strip in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

The problem is that I wanna obtain the sample plot, but here my qqplot datapoints are lying ON the strip. I don't know how to change that.

Here is the desired result:
[image: Desired result]
[image: my result]

What I obtained:

[image]

this is my code for the problem.

```
my_theme <-   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(size = 10),
                    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "gray50", size=3.5),
                    strip.clip="off",
                    strip.background = element_rect(color = "gray50",fill = "lightgray", size = 1.5),
                    legend.background=element_rect(fill = "lightgray", color="gray50", size=1.5),
                    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", size=4),
                    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                    legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
                    legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"))

ggplot(data = melted_df, aes(sample = value, color = Distribution)) +
  stat_qq(position = "identity") + geom_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Distribution, scales = "free") + xlab('Theoretical Quantiles') + 
  ylab('Sample Quantiles') + 
  ggtitle('QQ Plot for Different Distributions against Qnorm!') + my_theme
```

Comment: You made the strip and the background's line wider, you might need to play with the limits and `expand` to separate the plot from the background

Comment: what is expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify: The points are plotted on top of the `panel.background` not the `strip.background`.

One option to fix that would be to set `panel.ontop = TRUE` which also requires to set the fill color for the `panel.background` to `"transparent"`. This way the `panel.background` and all (!!) other `panel.xxx` elements defined by the theme are drawn on top of the plot.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on `ggplot2::mpg`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_theme <- theme(
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  plot.title = element_text(size = 10),
  panel.background = element_rect(
    fill = "transparent",
    color = "gray50", size = 3.5
  ),
  strip.clip = "off",
  strip.background = element_rect(
    color = "gray50",
    fill = "lightgray", size = 1.5
  ),
  legend.background = element_rect(
    fill = "lightgray",
    color = "gray50", size = 1.5
  ),
  legend.key = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", size = 4),
  axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
  legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
  legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"),
  panel.ontop = TRUE
)
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_rect()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(sample = hwy, color = class)) +
  stat_qq(position = "identity") +
  geom_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free") +
  xlab("Theoretical Quantiles") +
  ylab("Sample Quantiles") +
  ggtitle("QQ Plot for Different Distributions against Qnorm!") +
  my_theme
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `panel.border` to your `theme`. This is a rectangular element which is always drawn over the panel:

```r
ggplot(data = melted_df, aes(sample = value, color = Distribution)) +
  stat_qq(position = "identity") + 
  geom_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Distribution, scales = "free") + 
  xlab('Theoretical Quantiles') + 
  ylab('Sample Quantiles') + 
  ggtitle('QQ Plot for Different Distributions against Qnorm!') + 
  my_theme +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, linewidth = 3.5, 
                                    color = 'gray50'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide a reproducible example, but the problem is likely that you are using libraries to make the qqplot and add the qq line. These libraries do not play well with your thicker borders. It is likely that they are modifying the `expand` argument of `scale_x_continuous`.

See an example here (only showing the last set of plots, since those are the ones that go onto the axis and would be plotted on top of your panel border):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(
  data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                    y = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                    facet = c('A', "A", "A", "A")),
  aes(x, y)
) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~facet)

ggplot(
  data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                    y = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                    facet = c('A', "A", "A", "A")),
  aes(x, y)
) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~facet) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "gray50", size=3.5)
  )

ggplot(
  data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                    y = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                    facet = c('A', "A", "A", "A")),
  aes(x, y)
) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~facet) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "gray50", size=3.5),
    strip.clip = "off",
    strip.background = element_rect(color = "gray50",fill = "lightgray", size = 1.5)
  ) 


ggplot(
  data = data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                    y = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                    facet = c('A', "A", "A", "A")),
  aes(x, y)
) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  facet_wrap(~facet) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(0, 0))
```

[image]